# Prevent context menu in Edge when text is selected

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, microsoft-edge

In its recent version, Edge shows a context menu when selecting text. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour with JavaScript? I tried
`window.oncontextmenu = e => {e.preventDefault();};` but this wasn't successful.[image]

Comment: You can use the css properties `user-select: none` or `pointer-events: none` on the wanted tag but it can be blocking for behaviors like text selection.

Context menu is unfortunately only dedicated to the right-click context menu.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't need to use this feature in Edge, you can disable this menu via specific setting in Edge.

Just follow these steps:

1. Naviagte to `edge://settings/appearance` in Edge.
2. Scroll down the page to the `Context menus` section.
3. Disable the option `Show mini menu when selecting text`.

Something like this:

[image]

In addition, you can also disable this feature on specific sites, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onmouseup = event => event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [Dmitry Korenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71649638/prevent-context-menu-in-edge-when-text-is-selected/71784670#71784670) tip, I made a version that adds the event only if the browser is Edge.

The problem with this event is that to cancel a selection you need to click outside the selected elements.
This creates a problem because if you select everything with CTRL + A you cannot remove the selection as there is no unselected element to click on. That's why I made the second event that cancels the selection when double-clicking.

```
function disableEdgeMiniMenu() {
    if (/Edg\//.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) { // if it's edge (chromium-based)
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", event => event.preventDefault())
        window.addEventListener("dblclick", () => window.getSelection().empty())
    }
}
```